# Extract Tabular Data from PDF - RAEX File

Tags: java, parsing, pdf, extract

I want to extract and parse data from a tables on a pdf file structured as (Raex [file](http://www.gsma.com/newsroom/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/IR.21-v9.1.pdf)).

The Raex file s about a GSMA Roaming Database and contain many tables with datas of the operators.

There's some API like Tabular but the extracting data is not automatised I have to extract and clean data by hand.  I tried also PdfTables API but it's limited and not free.

Please I need just a route to parse all the tabulars data with java. The purpose is to make it readily accessible with a front-end

Please help,

Comment: *pdf file structured as (Raex file)* - have you made sure that they'll never change the outward appearance or inner structure of those PDFs?

Comment: This is an standard format from GSMA Orginszation, It can't be changed

Comment: I need your help guys !